# Angular 4 Animations don't work (no errors)

Tags: angular, animation, npm, package

I just installed the @angular/animations, I dont get any errors but I tried a lot of animations but don't work, nothing happening.

```
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition,
  keyframes
} from '@angular/animations';

    animations: [
        trigger('cefac', [
            state('da', style({
                opacitiy: 0.0,
            })),
            state('nu', style({
                opacity: 1.0,
            })),
            transition('da <=> nu', animate('1000ms ease-in')),
        ])
    ]

    pula: string = 'nu'; 

    plm(): void {
        this.pula = (this.pula === 'nu') ? 'da' : 'nu';
        alert ( this.pula );
    }
```

I think the depencies have some old ?

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.1.5"
  }
```

How to fix this problem? 
details details detalis details details detalis details details detalis details details detalis details details detalis details details detalis details details detalis details details detalis details details detalisdetails details detalisdetails details detalisdetails details detalisdetails details detalis